# usar phpmailer a través de proxy

Tags: php, phpmailer, gmail, puertos, proxy

Les comento mi caso, estoy intentando hacer un sistema de envío de correos automáticos con la libreria phpmailer, el caso es que ya la tengo programada y en mi pc con mi router casero y demás funciona. Pero el problema es que tengo que implantarlo en un servidor de una red corporativa, cuya salida a internet es a través de proxy en plan xxxxxxx puerto 8080. Al ejecutar el php este no funciona y no envía el correo.Este es el código que tengo en php:

```
    <?php 
    require 'G:/XAMMP/htdocs/Proyecto_everis/correo/PHPMailer/PHPMailer-5.2.16/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
     $mail = new PHPMailer();

    /***Configuracion php mailer**/
    $mail->isSMTP();
$mail->Host ='smtp.gmail.com';
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = 'xxxxxxx@gmail.com';
$mail->Password = 'xxxxx';
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->Port = 587;
/*================*/

/*========*/


/*=======*/

/*configuracion de correo a enviar*/
$mail->setFrom('xxxxxx@gmail.com','AVISADOR!!!');
$mail->addAddress('xxxxxn@gmail.com');

$mail->Subject = 'Prueba de phpmailer';
$mail->Body = 'Prueba de sistema de avisos automático';
/******************/


/*Envio de email*/
if($mail->send() == false){
    echo "No se pudo enviar";
    echo "ERROR DEL PHPMAILER ".$mail->ErrorInfo;
}else{echo "El correo se envio correctamente";}
/*=============*/


 ?>
```

El caso es que se ejecuta y no me dice el error y no se me llega a ejecutar la parte de código:

```
/*Envio de email*/
if($mail->send() == false){
    echo "No se pudo enviar";
    echo "ERROR DEL PHPMAILER ".$mail->ErrorInfo;
}else{echo "El correo se envio correctamente";}
/*=============*/


 ?>
```

Si fueran tan amables de ayudarme os lo agradecería enormemente

Saludos

Comment: Activa el debugger en phpmailer y verás lo que pasa https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/SMTP-Debugging
Habla con tu administrador de sistemas y que te abra/redireccione los puertos

Comment: El problema es que el codigo se para en la sentencia send, lo he comprobado con echos, y claro al no terminar de ejecutar no me sale el debug